# Generating Random Standard normal distribution number using box-muller method

Tags: c#, gaussian

I need to generate Random standard normal distribution numbers between 0 and 1 both included with mean 0 and Standard dev 1. The problem is that although code is working the random numbers generated are not between 0 and 1.

This is the method using Box-muller algorithm:

```
public double NextGaussian()
    {
            double u1 = r.NextDouble();
            double u2 = r.NextDouble();
            double left = Math.Cos(2.0 * Math.PI * u1);
            double right = Math.Sqrt(-2.0 * Math.Log(u2));
            double z = left * right;
            return this.mean + (z * this.standardDeviation);          
    }
```

Then in the main method:

```
Gaussian g = new Gaussian(0.0, 1.0);
double a = g.NextGaussian();
```

I expect variable a to have a value between 0 and 1 both included, but the actual output are all the numbers

Comment: can you provide rest of code?

Comment: This question doesn't make any sense; a normal distribution that is clamped to a particular range is *not a normal distribution*, so asking why you're not getting that is a strange question. Can you explain in much more detail what you believe a "normal" distribution is, and why you believe it should have a limited range? The whole *point* of a normal distribution is that any value can be sampled from it.

Comment: Hi @EricLippert, this is a question I have in an assignment. The scenario is:

In a 3 dimensional scenario, lines within a unit square are selected as described below:
Define a line within the unit cube by its two end-points:
(1, 1, 1) and (2, 2, 2), where 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2 ∈ [0, 1]

The Question asked in the assignment is then :

In a variation of the 3-dim problem above, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2 are generated using (0, 1). In other words, the coordinates of the line are generated using the standard normal distribution (mean 0 and standard deviation 1).

Comment: Then the assignment needs a great deal of clarification; I would talk to your instructor or teaching assistant and ask what the distribution is intended to be, because "normally distributed on a unit cube" doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

I think you problen lies in a missunderstanding of the normal distribution. A normal distribution gives you numbers in range `(-inf, inf)`. Although the larger the absolute value the less probable the number is (not linear). You can see that on every picture of a normal distribution. To put it simple the mean is the value of the hightest probability and the standard deviation defines how peaky the curve is,

Since you want only values in `[mean, mean + standard dev]` i recommend to tweak the distribution a little and use the absolute value of the random number (in relation to the mean) and cut that at the standard deviation treating this value as the value of `mean + standart dev`.

```
public static double NextRandomWithinStandardDeviation(this Gaussian gaussian)
{
    return Math.Min(
        Math.Abs(gaussian.NextRandom() - gaussian.Mean) + gaussian.Mean,
        gaussian.Mean + gaussian.StandardDeviation
    );
}
```

However this will not be truely normal distributed. In fact 21.73% of all generated random numbers will be outside of your interval, witch raises the probability to get `mean + standard deviation` significantly.

An other approach could be to generate random number, until the generated number is within the interval. This could theoretically take forever, but probability to get a number outside of the interval after the fifth iteration is less than 0.01%.

```
public static double NextRandomWithinStandardDeviation(this Gaussian gaussian)
{
    double randomNumer;
    do
    {
        randomNumber = Math.Abs(gaussian.NextRandom() - gaussian.Mean) + gaussian.Mean;
    }while(randomNumber > gaussian.Mean + gaussian.StandardDeviation);

    return randomNumber;
}
```